# how i can check if an array contains only "1" in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to check in a more elegant and generic way as possible if an Array only contains `"1"`.

Consider that the index of the array correspons to a thread index, and that threads set the corresponding index to `"1"` when they finished their job.

I've to check when all thread have finished their job, or in other word when the array only contains `"1"`.

I've done that in the "main"

```
Object obj =  new Object();
int[] flag = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
int [] ss = new int[]{1, 1, 1};
for (int i = 0; i < flag.length; i++) {         
    new Thread(new MioThread(i, flag, ss, 1, 0, bw, obj)).start();      
}
synchronized (obj) {
    obj.wait();
}
```

while I've done that at the end of the "run" method:

```
synchronized (flag) {
    flag[threadIndex] = 1;
    boolean ok = true;
    for(int i = 0; i< flag.length; i++){
        if(flag[i] == 0)
            ok = false;
    }
    if(ok) {
        synchronized(obj) {
            obj.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? Is there something about this that you're having trouble with?

Comment: yes, i'm looking for some suggestions. The way i've done in not so elegant.

Comment: @ user: At the very least, show how you've done it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad design.

If you want a blocking mechanism - just use a semaphore - each thread will release one permit and your "joined" thread will just attempt to acquire NUM_OF_THREADS permits.

If you want non-blocking design you can use an atomic integer
And if you want asynchronity - the thread that cause this atomic integer to become zero should call some callback.

Answer (score 3):

As you have to check every element in the array you will have to use a for loop. However I would suggest using an `AtomicInteger` set to the number of threads and decremented every time a thread finishes. All threads have finished when the number reaches zero.

Comment: more specifically..i've a for loop that run a certain number of threads, i have another for loop that have to run other threads only when the threads of the first loop have finished their job.

Comment: If you give an example of the code you're using I can give specifics of how you could update it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you have stated but as others have said there are better ways than using arrays of flags. There is no error handling here and in reality you wouldn't want to set allOnes to true at the start in case you get an exception that breaks you out of the loop without checking all the indexes but for a quick and dirty example it'll do.

```
boolean allOnes = true;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] != 1){
        allOnes = false;
        break;
    }
}
```